# Rails 4: Routing with partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I get the following error when navigating in my Rails application:
No route matches

```
{:action=>"startnew", :controller=>"tickets", :ticket_id=>4} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The problem is, I have a route for:

```
  post   'tickets/:id/startnew' => 'tickets#startnew', as: :start_new
```

This works fine, when I navigate to the URL `http://localhost:3000/tickets`
But the error occurs when I load the URL `http://localhost:3000/tickets?id=4`, which in my case needs to work, because I render tickets#list and tickets#show in two partials on tickets#index, where the error above occurs. 
When I click on a link on a different page the tickets#index is loaded and  the tickets#show is only rendered when I have the parameters in the url (`http://localhost:3000/tickets?id=4`).

In show I have this part, which causes the problem:

```
<%= link_to 'Book time', start_new_path(ticket_id: @ticket.id), method: :post, class: "button info block-shadow-info text-shadow", remote: true %>
```

Can you please give me a hint!

Comment: Change `:ticket_id` to `:id` in the parameters, or change the route to

`post 'tickets/:ticket_id/startnew' => 'tickets#startnew', as: :start_new`

Comment: can you run `rake routes | grep start` and share the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches {:action=>"startnew", :controller=>"tickets",
>   :ticket_id=>4} missing required keys: [:id]

You have

```
post   'tickets/:id/startnew' => 'tickets#startnew', as: :start_new
```

It means it expects `:id` as a key, but you are sending `:ticket_id`. Changing your link to below should work.

```
<%= link_to 'Book time', start_new_path(id: @ticket.id), method: :post, class: "button info block-shadow-info text-shadow", remote: true %>
```